# Get the path of each row in an attribute table and put it in a path field in the attribute table

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, attribute-table

[image]

How do I create a new field in this attribute table and populate it with the path of each row in the attribute table using PYTHON? I know there is a way to do this in ArcGIS Pro using the `"ADD_SOURCE_INFO"` parameter with the merge tool but I am using ArcMap 10.8.1 here.

I have this attempt but it gives the same path to everything.

```py
desc = arcpy.Describe("Database Connections\\DATACONV.sde\\DataConv.GISAD.Green_Stormwater_Infrastructure_Feature")
for child in desc.children:  
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(merged_polygons_py, "Source_SMP_Type", "'{}'".format(child.baseName), "PYTHON_9.3")
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way is to add a new field named "FilePath" with the same length to every source feature and populate with the path to the dataset **before** you merge.
You can remove the "FilePath" from the source after the merge.

The more complex way would be to use python.

1. create new destination feature class with the correct structure, plus a field for the file path.
2. Iterate through the source files, make sure to get the full path to the file.
3. Use the arcpy.da.SearchCursor to read the source data.
4. Use the arcpy.da.InsertCursor to append the source data, and path to the destination.
   If you want performance load the values from the da.SearchCursor into a dictionary, then insert tuples via the da.InsertCursor

You can achieve the same effect with model builder, using iterators, append and field calculators